# opening cd drive in assembly

Tags: assembly

how can i open cd drive in assembly(masm 6.1)?
platform is 32bit and os is windows
thanx

Comment: What is your hardware platform (PC, other, 64bit/32bit/16bit, etc), and what is your Operating System (Windows, Linux, BSD, None)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is the x86 interrupt, then it's an INT 13 call using the AH=46h method.

Reminds me of my old days hacking my 8088 with Peter Norton's book by my side.

Comment: thank you unknown (yahoo) (sorry i don't know your name)
i find out list of interruption and the link is : http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try a web search for open-source CD burning software.

[Here's one.](http://infrarecorder.org/)